# Azure, SQL Server and Database

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-storage

One of my customer is developing multi-tenant solution. And I'm working as developer for the automation of resource provisioning part. The solution is developed such that each tenant have their resources separate from each other.

So for example, a single tenant will require a SQL database (PAAS), A Storage Account, and also many other resources.

One of the requirement that, customer set is, he wants to have X number of databases to be hosted on a SQL server (a logical server not VM). Which I don't think is valid having been using SQL as PAAS.

**So My question is, Should we create SQL Server and SQL database for each tenant?**

Or

**Should we create a SQL server then host X number of databases on that server. when server reaches limits (X databases), create another server and execute same logic.**

**In either scenario, what difference does it make from Database Performace, Pricing and Database security point of view?**

*FYI, My thinking is that, If I host 'X' database on a single SQL Logical Server or If I create 'X' SQL Logical Server for 'X' SQL database hosting, It won't make any difference from Pricing and Database Performace point of view.*

Answer (score 0):

Few differences i could think of, if you go with single server for all clients..

1.Administrator Password is per Server and using this,one client can have access to other databases as well..
2.Azure has a limit of how many DTU's can be capped under one server,so if you have many databases under one server..This may lead to few issues like
  a.)frequent DTU increase requests
  b.)some times automated backup may fail,if there are no DTU's available(Backup needs to copy the whole database,so in this process ,DTU's needed will be equal to database which is backed up)

Comment: regarding 1) - clients usually do not connect to database with the **Adminitrator password**, you still have, and are advised to use, the option to create database contained users for application purposes; 2.a) you can use Elastic Database Pools, which is designed exactly for Multi-tenant solutions; 2.3) cannot really comment on that because there is no documentation provided.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too broad, as there are many opinions and approaches to your question.

But in any way you should take a look at elastic database pools: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-elastic-pool/ which is a feature exactly designed for multi-tenant SaaS solutions.

Your end solution may be a combination of both - you may want to use a single server to "bigger" tenants, while you can host multiple small tenants together in a single server.

Security shall not be a factor with big weight because, when you use database contained credentials for application access, it does not really matter whether the databases are allocated in single logical server or not.

Comment: The only problem I see here is, how my code based requires changes... As I can remember, I would need a wrapper around DBContext for connecting with Elastic SQL and the same won't work with SQL as PAAS.

Comment: I had already reviewed Elastic Pool and had sent this question to Microsoft, Thinking of scalability point of view, if we use elastic pool (which supports max of 400 databases in single premium pool), how do we handle case when it requires more databases? (obviously we’ll create another elastic pool but the point is how application will know that “ContosoDB” is in elastic pool 1 not 2?

Comment: And another question: Is there any way by which we can support both elastic pool and standalone database in application? (We may want some of our customer to have their standalone database but for low cost customers, it can be in elastic pool). In such case, we are left with no choice other than maintaining 2 source repository right?